# How to change the spin-orbit coupling strength in VASP?

Tags: vasp, spin-orbit-coupling

Since the effect of spin-orbit coupling plays an important role in a topological insulator, How to change the spin-orbit coupling strength in `VASP`?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to our community!

Answer (score 4):

> How to change the spin-orbit coupling strength in VASP?

Firstly, one can't realize this just by changing the input parameters in the `INCAR` for `VASP`. To tune the strength of spin-orbit coupling in `VASP`, you need to modify the source file `vasp_source_code_path/src/relativistic.F` and recompile it. For example, if you want to reduce the strength to half you can just multiply `0.5d0` to the $L \cdot S$ term in line 129 of `relativistic.F`:

```
       DO I=0,1
       DO J=0,1
       DO M =1,2*LL+1
       DO MP=1,2*LL+1
          DLLMM(LMP+MP-1,LM+M-1,J+2*I+1)=DLLMM(LMP+MP-1,LM+M-1,J+2*I+1)+ &
          0.5d0*SUM*LS(M,MP,I+2*J+1,LL)   !!!line 129 relativistic.F file
       END DO
       END DO
       END DO
       END DO
```

Note that you need to use the recompiled $vasp_ncl$ to run your calculation. As a benchmark, if you multiply `0.0d0` to the $L \cdot S$ term in line 129 of `relativistic.F` then you will receive the same result as the result obtained with `vasp_std`.

PS1: The answer is for the vasp.5.4.4.

PS2: You may take a look at [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.93.224425) about the implementation of spin-orbit coupling in `VASP`. Or you may take a look at this post in matter modeling: [Regarding spin-orbit coupling on DFT codes](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4456/regarding-spin-orbit-coupling-on-dft-codes/4463#4463).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thacks for your answer. I will try to check it.

Comment: Is this legal? I mean, from the physical point of view...

Comment: @Camps Mathematically meaningful. The SOC effect of real materials is hardly changed. Maybe you can only replace the atoms to realize that.

Comment: My concern is that, using that hack, you can fake the results.

Comment: @Camps I guess the method is generally adopted just to investigate the gradual behavior of SOC.

Comment: Just reminding people of the VASP chat room in case more discussion is needed!

Comment: This may be  a good way to understand the underlying physics in a system. It's more like a physical model.

Comment: +1 but I wanted to bring this new question to your attention: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9912/5 Do you think you can answer it?

Comment: @NikeDattani Sorry, I cannot answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for at least taking a look at it :) Do you understand what the question is asking by the way? I don't understand it!

Comment: I've substantially improved the question now, after learning more from the OP: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9912/5.